# Is there a way to derive a struct like with Deserialize to get automatic transform from serde_json::Value?

Tags: json, rust, serde

Deserialising from a string directly into a struct works perfectly. But in some cases, you may already have a `serde_json::Value` in your hands, and want to try and convert it into a struct.

The following example illustrate just that: loading a `Request` struct from JSON (in a network library for example), with a type string and a generic content as a Value, and then you want to call a handler (from a client library) with the value transformed into a given struct.

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json::{json, Value};
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Request {
    #[serde(alias = "type")]
    req_type: String,
    content: Value
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8
}

// It there a way to avoid having to declare this???
impl TryFrom<Value> for Person {
    type Error = serde_json::Error;

    fn try_from(value: Value) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Person::deserialize(value)
    }
}

fn say_hello(p: Person) {
    println!("Hello, I'm {}, and I'm {} years old!", p.name, p.age);
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let req: Request = Request::deserialize(json!({
        "type": "sayHello",
        "content": {
            "name": "Pierre",
            "age": 32
        }
    }))?;

    match req.req_type.as_str() {
        "sayHello" => say_hello(req.content.try_into()?),
        _ => println!("unknown request")
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

So the question is: is there some `derive` or other magic implemented which would allow the same behaviour as `Deserialize` from String, so that the client can only write:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8
}

fn say_hello(p: Person) {
    println!("Hello, I'm {}, and I'm {} years old!", p.name, p.age);
}
```

I tried the `#[serde(try_from = "Value")]` attribute but it does not look like it's intended for that purpose...

Comment: *"Deserialising from a string directly into a struct works perfectly"* - can you provide a case where a string works but a `Value` doesn't? There is no automatic conversion for either. `let p: Person = "data".try_into()?;` won't compile. Both require some kind of `deserialize()` call somewhere.

Comment: There is no reason to use Value in your case so.

Comment: @Stargateur this example is not to be taken literally, I know I don't need a Value in that particular case, it was mostly to expose the point.

Comment: @kmdreko I was meaning using `serde_json::from_str` but as the answer suggests below, a simple `serde_json::from_value` was what I was looking for.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for not understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`serde_json::from_value()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.67/serde_json/fn.from_value.html) specifically for this:

```
pub fn from_value<T>(value: Value) -> Result<T, Error> 
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
```

Given any `serde_json::Value` and some [`T: DeserializedOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.130/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html), the function will deserialize the `Value` to that `T`, if possible.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. On the serde_json page there are a bunch of suggested way to convert stuff, but no mention to the `from_value`, so it may be worth proposing to add a little note about that.